# How to marshall utf-8 string in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, utf-8, marshalling

The function in question is part of the native C API for Sqlite, but the answer should be general. I'm surprised I couldn't find an answer.

The existing code looks like this, but just handles 8-bit ANSI.

```
// wrapper to handle marshalling and avoid nulls
public static string sqlite3_column_text_wrapper(IntPtr pstmt, int iCol) {
  var ptr = sqlite3_column_text(pstmt, iCol);
  if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero) return "";
  else return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
}

// wrapper to handle marshalling and avoid nulls // TODO: utf
public static string sqlite3_column_text_wrapper_utf(IntPtr pstmt, int iCol) {
  var ptr = sqlite3_column_text(pstmt, iCol);
  if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero) return "";
  else return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
}

[DllImport("sqlite3.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] public static extern IntPtr sqlite3_column_text(IntPtr pstmt, int iCol);
```

The question is how to do the same thing for utf-8, preferably without having to allocate a buffer and copy the data twice.

Surely there must be the "one best way"?

---

I found this: [C# callback receiving UTF8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194828/c-sharp-callback-receiving-utf8-string), which uses MultiByteToWideChar (twice) and StringBuilder. Might be the answer.

---

An answer proposed an unsafe solution. This makes the app unverifiable, which is too high a price if any other solution is available. No unsafe please.

Comment: I deleted my answer about Marshal.PtrToStringUni(), because as you point it it is for UTF-16, not UTF-8. Perhaps you should marshal a byte array into c# and convert it to string with Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes). But you'll need to somehow know the length of the byte array in order to marshal it.

Comment: @George: Funny thing is, I may finish up using this function because Sqlite has a text16() version. But you're right, it can't answer the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a byte pointer to a UTF8 encoded string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytePtr">The byte PTR.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static unsafe string BytePtrToStringUTF8(byte* bytePtr)
    {
        if (bytePtr == null) return null;
        if (*bytePtr == 0) return string.Empty;

        var byteBuffer = new List<byte>(1024);
        var currentByte = default(byte);

        while (true)
        {
            currentByte = *bytePtr;
            if (currentByte == 0)
                break;

            byteBuffer.Add(currentByte);
            bytePtr++;
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteBuffer.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Well, it's unsafe and it looks like it allocates a buffer and copies the data twice. Which is what I was trying to avoid.